# What is the use of the state argument that is passed to the push method of react router's history object?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

The `history` object that is available in react's `Route` component has a `push` method that accepts a location object and an optional `state` argument. I feel incomplete gaping clueless at this `state` object. I would love it if someone can shed a light as to when this `state` object can be of use, how it could be passed and then be retrieved to be of some use?

Comment: It's so you can keep track of the state of your app, for example on a catalogue page to keep track of selected filters when you view a product detail page then hit back to results.

Comment: state is something you would wanna use if you dont want to pass queries on url part,

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pass current state of component to your routed switched component and access there then use,
`this.props.history.push("/GoTo", { ...response })` so now state is been passed.
you can very well take or pass state on `GoTo` component using,
`const state = this.props.location.state`
API says like parsing data,

```
e.g.    this.props.history.push("/GoTo", { some: 'state' })
```